# Prevent particular method from using AfterMethod in TestNG test

Tags: java, unit-testing, annotations, testng

Simple problem - I have such **AfterMethod** in my TestNG test class

```
@AfterMethod
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    userService.deleteUser(userName);
}
```

And all methods using it as expected but there is one ugly guy

```
    @Test
public void testDeleteUser() throws Exception {
    createUser();
    assertNotNull(userService.findByUserName("user01"));
    userService.deleteUser(userName);
    assertNull(userService.findByUserName("user01"));
}
```

And he do not need **AfterMethod** so I get the message like

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attempt to create delete event with null entity
```

Adding something to entity at the end of this test method does the trick as well as caching exception but I'm looking for professional solution to force some methods from using After or Before methods with in class setup (so I don't need any external xml with groups).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move testDeleteUser() to separate class.

Comment: Thanx this is prabobly best answer for my problem - I asked few experienced developers and they gave me the same answer. Another case is if somebody looking for such workaround (as in my question) something must be wrong with design of a test...